# Change Images in ImageView with gestures

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to implement something to change between images in ImageView, like a image gallery.

I have this XML to show the ImageView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hsv_ScrollImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/id_imgFinal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>    
        </HorizontalScrollView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

My app show images that are in landscape mode, and this is the reason which I am using the HorizontalScrollView. Now I have the problem, I would try to implement something to change to other Image with some kind of gesture, but i don't know if the HorizontalScrollView is a problem for this. Can somebody help me with this? Which method is the most frequently used for this Activities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/) there is a nice tutorial with a ViewPager. You could even integrate with [Gesture-ImageView](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview/) to add zoom capabilities to the gallery.

Ah! don't forget to add [this patch](https://github.com/photo/gesture-imageview/commit/58445b80cee19eafd5436d8a5cf6df6fcec4af12) to Gesture-ImageView to better integration.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Gallery UI widget? It's exactly for scenarios like this. [Here's](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-gallery-widget-example-and-tutorial/) a tutorial for it and [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html).